# Nested flex-grow does not honor overflow:auto

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a nested styling whose parent flex container has several fixed height elements (flex-grow:0), and a single variable height section (flex-grow:1). The variable height section happens to be a similarly composed vertical flex box container, again consisting of several fixed height sections, and single variable height section.I want the variable height section to fill the available space, and use a scroll bar.

I can use flex styling to achieve this behavior with a single layer of flex box children, but as soon as I make the variable height child for the parent container a flex box container itself, then the overflow-y:auto ceases to work.

I have included two html snippets, the first is the working one level section,
and the second is the non-working layout that mimics the ultimate design that I would like to achieve, other than the middle item does not scroll.

Any assistance in what I need to change to make this work would be appreciated.

[jsfiddle of working snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/ormnc5ka/)

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; height:300px">
  <div style="flex-grow:0">
    top flex-grow-0
  </div>

  <div style="flex-grow:1; overflow-y:auto">

    <div style="height:1200px">
      middle flex-grow-1
    </div>

  </div>
  <div style="flex-grow:0">
    bottom flex-grow-0
  </div>
</div>
```

And the snippet with two layers that doesn't scroll
[jsfiddle of non-working snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/2r0oLdky/)

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; height:300px">
  <div style="flex-grow:0">
    top flex-grow-0
  </div>

  <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; flex-grow:1">

    <div style="flex-grow:1; overflow-y:auto">

      <div style="height:1200px">
        middle flex-grow-1
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="flex-grow:0">
    bottom flex-grow-0
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your code to a working snippet, so we can reproduce the problem. Thanks. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: My apologies.... The code was there, I just didn't get it formatted correctly in the text. I have adjusted the main post to correctly display the working and non-working snippets.

Comment: I think I have answered my own question. the key to correct behavior of the second snippet of code is  to add min-height:0 style ot the div on line 6